# I cannot create a POST request using POSTMAN, but I have no problems doing it on Swagger

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, swagger, postman

I have a Controller that can receive Post requests.

```
public IHttpActionResult PostCreaAlimento([FromBody] Alimento alimento)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return BadRequest("Invalid data.");

        return _repositorio.CreaAlimento(alimento) ? Ok(alimento) : (IHttpActionResult)NotFound();
    }
```

The request is correctly done on swagger, and I receive a response code 200.

But, if I try to do the same on POSTMAN, I receive an Unsupported Media File.

[Request on POSTMAN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gr74i.png)

Why is this not working :/

Comment: Thank to all of you!!!! I still don't understand a lot of stuff with http requests, but I'll keep doing tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using [FromBody] in the action it means that you need to send  application/json contentType
so select Body=> raw => json and put this in the body of Postman

```
{
    "AlimentoId":4,
    "Description":"testing",
    "Calorias" :400
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try **raw**, not **form-data**. Ensure that you choose **JSON**. Next prepare your data as a json object.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You pass json data as form data but your controller accepts request body data as raw data. You should change body type as raw data.